# Can I travel to the UK after having previously been denied a Tier 5 visa?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, us-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

[image: Refusal letter]

I went into the UK in October '15 coming from work in Japan and came to UK to see work clients. I didn't have a return flight but they still granted me to come in with a letter from my work. No issues.

Anyway, I came for two months (Oct-Dec) and left back to NYC (I am a US citizen) to do my UK visa. My type of visa was sponsorship so I believe Tier 5 type visa. I applied but was immediately denied due to the wrong paperwork my work (my modeling agency) provided me. The UK uses a point system and I got no points for the paperwork the modeling agency sent me.

Anyway, it's been almost three months and I have friends/boyfriend that I want to go visit next week.

Should I apply for a visitor visa?

Any legal advice anyone can give me?

I am strongly not going for work. Also I am staying with my best friend who lives/works in London.

[image: Visa]

Comment: PS. I brought a round trip flight. I have the sufficient funds in my bank account for my stay. I have proof of all my income up to date. my stay is only 10 days no longer. I do not intend to stay longer and I'm staying with best friend for free!

Comment: The general rule of thumb is that if you get a refusal or removal, then your next visit(s) should be on an entry clearance. But if you have already purchased tickets and are leaving next week, there's not enough time for that. Note that "should I apply for a visitor visa" is an opinion-based thing.

Comment: Take with you every scrap of evidence you can put together that you have a life in NYC that you are strongly motivated to return to. There is going to be a strong suspicion that you are really trying to immigrate and will throw away the return ticket. For example, do you have post-travel work lined up in NYC?

Comment: "Any legal advice anyone can give me?" Only a lawyer. We're not lawyers. We don't and can't give legal advice.

Comment: Can you scan and upload images of: (1) Your stamp in your passport from the most recent time you were granted leave to enter the UK, and (2) your visa refusal notice (with personal information blacked out)? These may be helpful in understanding your complete situation.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I agree. The refusal notice puts definitive shape on the OP's circumstances, even if it is from the PBS side. If the OP provides it and I spot it, I will hammer the question open and ping you so you can add the answer. Otherwise 'legal advice' type questions are 'opinion-based' or 'unclear' :)

Comment: Trying to add photo I don't know how to. But I have work back in Japan I'm due to be flying from NYC to TOKYO on may 9th.  And sorry I meant opinion based advice!!

Comment: @MichaelHampton I added the photos! Any advice would be great

Comment: By any chance should I have my boyfriend write a letter? He is a uk citizen thought it might help in my case because honestly just coming to visit him and my best friend. Don't care much for work... At the moment I am trying to leave that Modeling agency in London.

Comment: Opiniob based advice is **specifiically** off topic here. A letter from your boyfriend is neither here nor there. A letter from the friend you are staying with (and their landlord/copy of their contract saying) both saying it is fine for you to stay on the other hand.

Answer (score 3):

Legal advice is something that nobody is qualified to do (or could legally do here).

However, your broad questions of do you need/should you apply for a Visa is reasonably well covered [by the offical UK government visa checker](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/tourism):

> You won’t need a visa to come to the UK
>
> However, you should bring the same documents you’d need to apply for a visa, to show to officers at the UK border.
>
> **You may want to apply for a visa if you have a criminal record or you’ve previously been refused entry into the UK.**

You've been refused a work visa in the past. This will show up when you arrive in the UK. For any future entry, or any visitor visa application, you're going to have to try quite hard to convince the authorities that you don't intend on trying to work.

Your liklehood (or lack thereof) of obtaining a Visa I wouldn't care to comment on. [You can find out more about UK visitor visas, along with application guidance on gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/tourist-short-stay-visas)

Comment: Being refused entry is a completely different thing to being refused a visa.